# Terms request for something like "big picturely great" or "roughly great" work, results, person (as owner of those considered traits)

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, phrase-request

I look for correct and **short** **terms** describing following meanings

**1)** "Highly good in **big picture** but not in **all not most important rank things** (from details to midway important degree) and also maybe not much in **orderliness** (work / project model / worker / businessperson / trait of person)

**2)** "Highly good in **focusing** and (**work results / investing of efforts**) on **most important** parts/work_elements (work / project model / worker)". Like that working **total output/results** in long term (one month or one year) consideration can be better with focusing on most important things with just skipping investing/wasting time and focus on less than that important things

**3)** "Having **some very good** qualities (option / worker) while there can be other options where a lot of them **different or worse** (in types and amount and degree) considering **all related** qualities big picture"

Also I would want to know are following terms that I personally created for those meanings being at least logically and linguistically somewhat okay? They are **"big picture great/efficient things"** and **"roughly great/efficient things"**

Comment: Hi, @KateBunting. You said you did not understand one my past question. I changed it for: more highlighting of important things; explaining with contexts for usage of the things I ask about; grammatically more normal/regular for understanding form. Please answer

Comment: The best versions I can come up with are (1) Very good overall, but lacking in detail and organisation. (2) Very good in that efforts were focussed on the most important aspects of the project. (3) I don't understand. Do you mean that some workers have good qualities while other workers are of a much worse standard?

Comment: ...and, no, you can't use 'big picturely' as an adverb. 'Excellent overall' would be a possibility. 'Roughly great' doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @KateBunting, also, what can be **short/concise terms** for one being always **"rough"** or inconsiderate/not_investing/lacking_of_goodness at not even details (which was not fitting there word) but all non maximally important aspects person generally (like as business owner, worker, person for others, person for oneself in cultivation of heath and intellectual abilities, maybe all simultaneously) that focusing/investing efforts/resources on something like most important things or aspects of projects (including relationships, healthy lifestyle, and genius abilities developing projects)

Comment: @KateBunting, I understand that "roughly great" in close context/contrast with "big picture" concept can be making audience to have some lack of important related associations but usually it's more obviously implying "big picture" cause "rough greatness" is used as some general assessment or assessment of big picture because it's having even less sense/correctness_feeling otherwise and it seems natural to use it for assessing whole person, general work, trait. With that perspective about "rough greatness" in mind,please consider previously written logic about it, it's not stubbornness or stuff

Comment: @KateBunting. also, what do you think about concept of "macro great/efficient things"? It can be short, at least partially including big picture concept/perspective/assessment. But also it can be somewhat limiting, because if the roughly great things concept is correct, by my feeling understanding it can be better in being more wide and about all kinds of things and their exclusive big picture and not always some most or significant macro picture and also undesirable focus on their maternal concepts/things/containers(like project for project part) or stuff, I don't know how to describe it much

Comment: Your language is so convoluted that I'm having difficulty in following your train of thought. _Roughly great_ would not be understood by a native speaker of English. From your reply to JavaLatte below, you seem to mean something like "His methods may have been rough and ready https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rough-and-ready , but they were effective in the long run."

Comment: @KateBunting, maybe. I wanted to get exactly logically and associativity efficient and concise concepts for regular use in my systems and interface & regular genius ideas thinking & stating stuff in living & my projects with definition there. Correspondingly, probably there will be either finding some rare concepts or creating original ones. That's why I said all those original concepts and that logic and possible associations of people not just casually using them (but use specific important meaning). I wanted assessing and maybe altering from masters like you. Is it for engli language&usage?

Comment: @KateBunting,I guess I firstly was able to goodly describe both meaning for which I search terms and term "roughly great things" for it in 2 comments to JavaLatte. 2nd comment is especially important because that's abou being not only strategic or certain fields working or usage of already acquired skills and knowledge only but also general private life cultivating/working/improving, & subjectivity/situationality of "greatness", & "roughness" 1 way possibly being focus on doing currently possible/okay_to_do & most beneficial,where being at the edge is "great" and it still big picturely "rough"

Answer (score 1):

1) You can use the term [strategic](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/strategic) to describe focussing on the big picture (the strategy) and the antonym is tactical- focussing on the details (tactics).

2) The important stuff is high priority, so you could describe somebody as being priority-driven.

3) Something that has good qualities and is better than others is [superior](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/superior).

Comment: Can Points 1) and 2) be partially combined into "roughly great" person/working/works? Such person and their projects can be **rough** or inconsiderate (not investing) and **lacking** high goodness (and being not **overall** great at not all elements and even "fabric" of **all** elements from details to even midway important things would be lacking investing as much as most important things) at all non maximally to significantly important aspects. But still they would have with all this often bigger efficiency in long term and big picture and certain fields (like startup, main ideas, managing)

Comment: @Sage123 **roughly** as an adverb qualifying an adjective generally means  **appproximately**. Is that what you intended it to mean in **roughly great**?

Comment: I guess not. Imagine "roughly great" work like business/private_life_plans vision, investments gathering presentation, main idea model, results of working as director or president, where there are tons of small and medium issues and need for some delegating altering modeling and models realization engineering but in big picture the frame, foundation, directing of that work is having tons of important things/elements where investing time on all those small issues but loosing one or few of them would be worse in big picture for that work in efficiency/intended_benefits, sustainability, potential

Comment: it's also cultivation progressing, instead of comfort zone leaving bad feels with doing&preparing everything, overweight&addicted person can do roughly currently (where that subjective/situational greatness overtime will gradually change) great progressing with only doing some most basic calories calculating, exercising just with schedule & random moving, sleeping by schedule, and generally gradually develop knowledge & systems & practical performing of them with focusing only on most beneficial things which will be currently "great" and better than nothing or degrading and "rough"

Comment: 3rd separate meaning of "roughly great things" can be in my logic writing/creating great/genius(creative,wise,importantly intelligent) ideas but not much caring about most conventional language rules and using tons of slang grammatical construction and own original and not exactly by speech parts words and concepts, and also not caring much about punctuation, and maybe even just as meaning explaining, adding some swears and stuff because it's emotionally buffing or helping and making it all more meaningful while all this is in big pic great and unimportantly rough in rules of easy fix/ignore

Comment: @Sage123 ... so what you want is one word that means absolutely everything?

Comment: not exactly. I just gave some logic on maybe possible utilizations of "roughly great things". I have no certainty if the logic in general and also linguistic sense is correct & if the term have good alternatives/option_terms. I would very want some terms for 1 and 2 meanings generally (your suggested concepts were very great btw) and combinationally, so does the logic for that term for them makes sense, or maybe there can be some other alternatives? But yeah, if all 3 meanings can be united into one thing it would be great & still limited in those very important meanings & contextually obvious

Comment: also that "context" includes themes additions which will specify things but still keep the important general direction and also mental strenghtening of that general concept very important for a lot of uses and places with just their unique theme additions or simplified use. Examples:there can be resources operating and acquisition business path rough greatness orientation with focusing on their most important things and delegating/ignoring idea creation and other things and just operating other people's ideas; there also can be contrastly roughly great ideas and orienting with creation of them

Comment: @Sage123 (sigh).

Comment: please elaborate. Situation overview: you possibly expressed not understanding of universality and maybe generally logic of that term; I told how it can be a little more universal than your suggestions but still have enough limits of meaning that is pretty unique and desirable/great enough for being regular in use and correspondingly deserve some terms. Maybe you deleted a comment that was uneditable here (more than 5 minutes old), and thought an altered version but was distracted to post? I can be pretty dumb and do a lot of logic & originality ending badly, but it's a need for developing

Comment: also maybe there can be similar "overview great things" concept. Because "overview - a general summary of a subject", "overviewing - a general outline of a subject or situation", "outline - a general description or plan giving the essential features of something but not the detail. Similar: rough idea" (also literally including that "rough idea" by google search "definitions of outline" and google's widget of some dictionary which maybe additionally clears understanding and maybe supports that my term)

Comment: @Sage123: you write in a kind of shorthand- very long sentences without a proper grammatical structure. They are difficult to understand. Try to restrict yourself to ten to fifteen words per sentence. Make each sentence complete and grammatical. Choose your words carefully.